# "ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made" When Trying To Connect To A Server

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, client

I am trying to run this code using sockets:

```py
address = ip = input('>>>')
if ip == '0':
    address = (socket.gethostname(), 65535)
    s.connect(address)
```

And it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/*****/Desktop/Lightspace/Lightspace.py", line 61, in startupgame
    s.connect(address)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Why is it doing that? I have checked the server console, and everything looks fine. What is with this client-side issue?

Comment: What input are you giving the program? If `'0'`, do you have a TCP server actually running and listening on `localhost` on port `65535`?

Comment: yes on sockets.

Comment: please show the server code/console output.